# Plotting activation function gradients in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, torch, activation-function

Using a pytorch model I want to plot the gradients of loss with respect to my activation functions (e.g. ReLU). For the non-activation layers I can get gradients as follows but for the activation functions I cannot do that. How can I plot my activation functions. I need them to check for vanishing/exploding gradients problem. Thanks for your help.

I want to plot the gradients of my activation functions using torch to achieve something like the screenshot below.
[image]

```py
# Given a model defined like this how to get grads of torch.nn.ReLU() ?
model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(1,2), torch.nn.ReLU(), torch.nn.Linear(2,1), torch.nn.tanh())

# For non-activation layers I can do
print(model[0].grad)

# But I cannot do
model[1].grad
```

How can I get gradients for ReLU and tanh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReLU(x)=max(0,x) so the gradient is 0 if x<0, 1 if x>0 and undefined when x =0
so you could just take the output from the relu layer and plot the corresponding value.
[see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333394/what-is-the-derivative-of-the-relu-activation-function)

edit:

this is how you can get certain layers outputs, and after that manually compute the gradients.

**option one:**
You could create a `nn.module` class instead your `torch.nn.sequential`  to store and return your activation gradients.
something like:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(1,2)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 =  torch.nn.Linear(2,1)
        self.tanh =  torch.nn.tanh()

    def forward(self, x):
        out = {}
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        out['relu_out'] = x.detach()
        x = self.tanh(self.fc2(x))
        out['tanh_out'] = x.detach()
        return x,out
```

**option two:**

is using [forward hooks](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-l-load-my-best-model-as-a-feature-extractor-evaluator/17254/6)

Comment: when I do loss = loss_fn(model(x), target), and loss.backward() how can I do as you suggested ?

Comment: edited my answer with options to get the activation layers output